# Catch post_save signal

Tags: django, django-signals

**Django 3.0.5.**

**apps.py**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class NewsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'news'

    def ready(self):
        from .models import News # Breakpoint 0

        @receiver(post_save, sender=News)
        def handle_news_save(sender, **kwargs):
            print("Working")
            a = 0 # Breakpoint 1
```

**models.py**

```
class News(models.Model):
    news_text = models.TextField()
```

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
     ...
    'news.apps.NewsConfig',
]
```

**The problem**

At Breakpoint 0 the interpreter stops when I run the application. That is at the next line Django gets to know that I'm catching the signal.

But when I save an instance of News in admin site, at Breakpoint 1 the interpreter doesn't stop. And, of course, no printing happens.
Could you help me catch the signal?

Comment: Try adding an 'instance' parameter to the handle_news_save function:

def handle_news_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):

Also, did you add this to the __init__.py of your application?
default_app_config = 'yourproject.news.apps.ProfilesConfig'

Comment: Dear Eduardo, could you clarify, why do I need instance there? This is the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/signals/#django.dispatch.receiver As you can see, no instance exists in the given example. Then, why do I need that init.py if the only reason for that may be to be get to Breakpoint 0, to where the interpreter comes without any problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i tried it out and played with signals a little, here's what i found out:

As the question state this way of defining does not work it seems to not register the signal correctly. I have no clue why it doesn't.

I guess the convention about signals would be anyways to move them to a `signals.py` file and then in the `apps.py` you only import them.

signals.py:

```
from .models import News  # Breakpoint 0
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


@receiver(post_save, sender=News)
def handle_news_save(sender, **kwargs):
    print("Working")
    a = 0  # Breakpoint 1
```

apps.py:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


class PollsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'polls'

    def ready(self):
        import polls.signals
```

and then it works